# When should I use std::thread::Builder instead of std::thread::spawn?

Tags: rust

After reading these [`std::thread::Builder`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Builder.html) and [`std::thread::spawn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) I understand their differences (more or less), but is it recommended to use always [`std::thread::Builder`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Builder.html)?.

I do not understand why there are two; can someone explain to me when is best to use one or the other? Perhaps one or the other cannot or should not be used in some cases?

---

```
let child: std::thread::JoinHandle<()> = std::thread::spawn(move || {
      for a in 0..100{
        println!("D");   
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(50));
    }
});

child.join();
```

---

```
let child: Result<std::thread::JoinHandle<()>,_> = std::thread::Builder::new().name("child1".to_string()).spawn(move || {
    for a in 0..100{
        println!("D");   
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(50));
    }
});

child.unwrap().join();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation for `thread::Builder`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.Builder.html) answers all of your questions by listing all the functions and types that don't directly correspond to `thread::spawn`:

> ```
> fn name(self, name: String) -> Builder
> ```
>
> Names the thread-to-be. Currently the name is used for identification
>   only in panic messages.
>
> ```
> fn stack_size(self, size: usize) -> Builder
> ```
>
> Sets the size of the stack for the new thread.
>
> ```
> fn spawn<F, T>(self, f: F) -> Result<JoinHandle<T>>
>     where F: FnOnce() -> T,
>           F: Send + 'static,
>           T: Send + 'static
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Unlike the spawn free function, this method yields an `io::Result` to
>   capture any failure to create the thread at the OS level.

So a `thread::Builder` allows you to:

1. Set a thread name.
2. Set the stack size.
3. Handle an error to start the thread.

Use `thread::spawn` when you don't care about any of those.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really doubt arises for this in thread::spwan -> *Panics if the OS fails to create a thread; use Builder::spawn to recover from such errors.* I do not know if this will happen, or not so wondered whether it was better to always use Builder. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AngelAngel it depends; how do you plan on handling the failure? If you have something that makes more sense than panicking, then sure, use `Builder`.